# Logged in Facebook user's name if we have access token using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

How can I get Logged in Facebook user's name if I get access token using Javascipt or Jquery?Thanks in advance..

```
    var accessToken = '';
    accessToken=localStorage.getItem(facebook_token);
    params='access_token='+accessToken;
      $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me",params, 

        function(response){
            fbUesrName=response.name;
            alert(fbUesrName);
       },"json");
```

Comment: Have you read the docs? This is very simple. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already connected via the JavaScript SDK you could do something like this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});
```

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

**UPDATE**

If you have the access token of the current logged in user you can issue a HTTP GET at this URL https://graph.facebook.com/me You can then read the Json response.

Sample of jQuery code to do this:

```
// Set the access token here
var accessToken = '';

$.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me",
    type: "get",
    data: { access_token: accessToken},
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // You can access the name of the user this way:
        // response.name
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    complete: function () {
    }
});
```

**Edit**: I'm really confused now. Correct me if I'm wrong but you're developing a **web application off Facebook Canvas that is supposed to be accessed via a web browser on a Blackberry. You also don't want to use the Facebook JavaScript SDK (why?)**. In order to achieve what you want you should complete all the steps below. I'm under the impression you're trying to start directly from the last one.

1. You need to create a Facebook application:
   https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. You need to implement Facebook
   Login:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-without-js-sdk/
3. *Optionally*: you might need to ask for extended permissions
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions
4. When all of this is working and the current user has granted
   permission to your app and has logged in into it you can then use
   the code sample I provided.

Comment: Actually I am not using JavaScript SDK for Facebook connect, so I can not use this:(

Comment: Is your app a web app (canvas or off Facebook)? In both case you should use the JavaScript SDK to check the login status and query the graph API. Have a look at the link I provided, it explains how lo load and use the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: No SDKs and I am developing a Blackberry app and I am using ajax request to get the access token.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should have provided more details in your question (such as you were developing for the Blackberry platform).

Comment: How did you get the access token?

Comment: @Gabriel: Ya I have tried that code and I am passing the access token as parameter and I am getting the error:"bad request". Why is this?

Comment: Thank you so much Gabriel, I got the user's name:) and look at the code I am using and is almost similar to what you had suggested. I am not using SDk is because in Blackbery I am bringing the browser inside the app using childbrowser concept of phonegap and logging in to FB using the URL:https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize? and then proceeding. Any way thank you so much:)